# How to update a database on a remote machine in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails 3.1 app, which lets end user to add/update customer's information list. Now I have a request to sync this cust_info table with a db on a remote machine. So whenever a change has been made in Rails, it automatically update the remote db. What's the best way to approach this?

I'm thinking of setting up a remote db access in config/database.yml and create a model to establish a connection to that db. But in my controller, when a customer's info gets saved, how do I use that remote db connection to update one table? Should I write a raw sql query?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok if the cust_info has same structure both in current db as well as remote machine why not use replication feature on that table only

Comment: Never used replication feature. Could you please elaborate a bit or point to a reference? Thanks.

Comment: Well you using a relation database or any database for that matter (NoSql too these days support replication) they all support a feature called replication where you can replication your entire database or part of the database which other server .This is most essential used as a technique for fail over (if your main db-server go off etc) or speed optimization (write to one database and reading from other etc) . Depending on your need you can choose replication M-M replication(Master to Master) where write in either of the database is synced to other .

Comment: or Master to Salve where write to master database is synced to salve database . There are tons of article around there if you just google replication on your browser